# How to make display: flex and flex-wrap:wrap work on Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have a website that display the content very well on Chrome. But on the Safari it's broken.

`flex` does not work on Safari. How to fix it?

```css
.col-border {
  margin: 0;
}

.col-position,
.equal {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.equal {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-position col-border">
  <div class="line-hori">
    <div class="col-border-padding">
      <div class="content-top">
        <p>Intercommunalités, le mensuel</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content-top-date">
        <p>08/09/2017</p>
      </div>
      <a href="http://www.adcf.org/intercommunalites-mensuel">
        <img src="images/publication/Images-Publications-Interco221.jpg" class="img-publication img-middle" alt="...">
      </a>
      <h5 class="title-publication">
        <a href="http://www.adcf.org/intercommunalites-mensuel" style="color:#2a5caa;">Intercommunalités 221 – Biodiversité : 
             l’indispensable action locale</a>
      </h5>
      <p class="desc-publication">
        <a href="http://www.adcf.org/intercommunalites-mensuel" style="color: #000;">L'AdCF publie chaque mois 
             Intercommunalités, une revue réalisée par. 
            </a>
      </p>
      <a href="http://www.adcf.org/intercommunalites-mensuel">
        <img class="click-detail" src="/template/adcf_v3/public/img/lire.png" alt="Lire">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Safari? Safari 9+ supports `flexbox` **without** a prefix and Safari 6.1+ supports `flexbox` **with** a prefix.

Comment: @hungerstar I use safari 5.1.7 for windows.

Comment: You'll have to use the old flexbox syntax for that ancient, un-supported browser. [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) is a helpful resource for finding what which browsers support what.

Comment: @Ayuktia But _why_ are you using Safari 5.1.7 for Windows? According to [this article](https://www.pcper.com/news/General-Tech/Apple-No-Longer-Updating-Safari-Windows-Users-Should-Switch-More-Secure-Browser), published in late 2012, it had at least 121 known security holes.

Comment: @MrLister  I am using windows. Somebody told me that there's bug on safari. But I can't check it using my computer. So, I installed safari on windows. There's only 5.1.7 the latest version on windows.

Comment: Maybe you can borrow someone's iPhone.

Comment: That's not how to test other browsers. You need to find the browsers people are using, and use those, not terribly out of date browsers that nobody uses. The same problem arises for Mac users who want to test IE and Edge, they can't. Services like https://crossbrowsertesting.com/ are a nice solution.